# Error after adding AjaxControlToolkit's HTMLEditorExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Whenever I try to add AjaxControlToolkit's HTMLEditorExtender I get following exception:[image]

I didn't find any code block on my page. Except some that I don't think will effect this. Like library importing code and sql datasource tags. Some one suggested me that I need to remove and re-add the library and the tab containing ajax toolkit controls. I done that but then another error came up which I asked yesterday here [Error while running the website using AjaxControlToolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133631/error-while-running-the-website-using-ajaxcontroltoolkit) but solution suggested by others didn't worked. So I reset back to original situation. Please tell how to solve this issue? Also please tell why its showing user as "Stephen" in stacktrace's line 3,4,5? I don't have any user of that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using`<%# %>` instead of `<%= %>`

Might solve your issue.

Comment: thanks it worked. Actually the page doesn't has any <% %> blocks but the master page which it was inheriting has it. I found the complete explanation here: http://leedumond.com/blog/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blocks/

Answer (score 1):

Please do what you did before. Add the Ajax control toolkit latest [version](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/Download.ashx).
Then just drag and drop the control into the form. It will automatically add the toolkit reference to aspx page as well as in web.config file. This settings should work normally. If it didn't work you have to add it manually.
        <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

You must also add the assembly reference to web.config file as well.

```
 <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </assemblies>
```

This assembly may not work on your web.config if the versions are different. Please Try this